# How draw geometric figures on top on an existing pdf?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I need to draw a rectangle on top of an existing pdf. Here is what i do

```
public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String originalFile = "C:\\Users\\original.pdf"; 
        String modifiedFile = "C:\\Users\\modified.pdf"; 

        PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File(originalFile)); 
        PDPage page = (PDPage) doc.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().get(0);

        PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page  ); 
        drawRect(contentStream, Color.green, new java.awt.Rectangle(500, 500, 20, 200), true); 
        contentStream.close(); 
        doc.save(new File(modifiedFile) ) ; 

    }



    private static void drawRect(PDPageContentStream content, Color color, Rectangle rect, boolean fill) throws IOException {
        content.addRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
        if (fill) {
            content.setNonStrokingColor(color);
            content.fill();
        } else {
            content.setStrokingColor(color);
            content.stroke();
        }
    }


}
```

**However this creates a green rectangle on a blank page. I need that rectangle on top of the existing data. Do I save it correctly?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please change this line

```
PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page  );
```

to this:

```
PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, AppendMode.APPEND, true, true);
```

this will not only create an extra content stream, but also reset the graphics context.